# How to enable transactions in Aria(MariaDB)?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, mariadb

I`m new in MySQL and MariaDB. I replaced mysql with mariadb and have issue with transactions.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM             | YES     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| Aria               | YES     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | YES          | YES  | YES        |
+--------------------+---------+--------------+------+------------+

MariaDB [(none)]> create table test (id INT) ENGINE=ARIA TRANSACTIONAL=1


BEGIN;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
ROLLBACK;

WARNING:some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aria storage engine is not currently transactional.  From the [MariaDB site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/):

> TRANSACTIONAL is only applicable for Aria tables. In future Aria tables created with this option will be fully transactional, but currently this provides a form of crash protection.

Aria is planned to be transactional in the future, but it is not a priority.  Also from the [MariaDB site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-faq/):

> For the moment, Aria 2.0 is on hold as the developers are focusing their main efforts on improving MariaDB.

If you need a table to be transactional, use the InnoDB storage engine (which is actually [XtraDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/xtradb-and-innodb/)).  If you are replacing an existing installation that required transactions, the old tables must have been InnoDB since MyISAM is non-transactional.